# Source synchronization in Visual Studio CMake project and WSL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a big solution where part of projects is a classic Visual C++ projects and other part is CMake type projects.
Previously I work with Windows 7 + VS 2017 + Ubuntu on virtual machine and before start building CMake project for linux, VS start rsync for synchronization source between PC and virtual machine. 
For this I was create next rule in CMakeSettings.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Linux-Debug",
  "generator": "Unix Makefiles",
  "remoteMachineName": "${defaultRemoteMachineName}",
  "configurationType": "Debug",
  "remoteCMakeListsRoot": "/var/tmp/src/Solution_dir/",
  "cmakeExecutable": "/usr/bin/cmake",
  "buildRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\build\\${name}",
  "installRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\install\\${name}",
  "remoteBuildRoot": "/var/tmp/Solution_dir/build/x86_64_debug_unix",
  "remoteInstallRoot": "/var/tmp/Solution_dir/install/x86_64_release_unix",
  "remoteCopySources": true,
  "remoteCopySourcesOutputVerbosity": "Normal",
  "remoteCopySourcesConcurrentCopies": "10",
  "remoteCopySourcesMethod": "rsync",
  "remoteCopyBuildOutput": false,
  "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
  "buildCommandArgs": "",
  "ctestCommandArgs": "",
  "inheritEnvironments": [ "linux_x64" ],
  "remoteCopySourcesExclusionList": [ "Debug", "Release", ".intermediate", ".vs", "Setup" ]
}
```

And now I have installed Windows 10 Pro and WSL.
By default WSL have mount my local drives(like /mnt/c, /mnt/d) and in my opinion there no more sense to make a copy of source code folder.
But if I will change **remoteCMakeListsRoot** property to **"/mnt/d/Solution_dir"** VS will start rsync that will remove my .git folder and all folders from **remoteCopySourcesExclusionList** property.
If I will remove **remoteCopySourcesExclusionList** property from CMakeSettings.json rsync will remove .git folder anyway.

What is the true way to work with WSL from Visual Studio? How can I say to VS that no need to start rsync?

Comment: Maybe just `"remoteCopySources": false`?

Comment: How could I not see it? Fantastic! It's exactly want I need, thx!